# playing wmv files using javafx media class

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

i wanted to play `.wmv` in javaFX using media classes and this is the following way i have tried

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MoviePlayer extends Application{


public static void main (String [] args){
launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Group root = new Group();    
    try{
        //File f=new File("C:/Wildlife.wmv");
        //URI u=new URI("C:\\Wildlife.wmv");

    Media media = new Media("C:\\Wildlife.wmv");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView view = new MediaView(player);

    root.getChildren().add(view);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    player.play();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

but it is throwing following exception

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\Wildlife.wmv
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at MoviePlayer.start(MoviePlayer.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can any body please tell me how to solve it
**Update** 
Video not playing
[image]

**following is the code after error handling and the screenshot**

```
  import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaErrorEvent;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MoviePlayer extends Application{


public static void main (String [] args){
launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Group root = new Group();    
    String source="file:///C:/share/test.mp4";
    Media media;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    MediaView mediaView;
    try {
        media = new Media(source);
        if (media.getError() == null) {
            media.setOnError(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Handle asynchronous error in Media object.
                    System.out.println("Handle asynchronous error in Media object");
                }
            });
            try {
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
                if (mediaPlayer.getError() == null) {
                    mediaPlayer.setOnError(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // Handle asynchronous error in MediaPlayer object.
                            System.out.println("Handle asynchronous error in MediaPlayer object.");
                        }
                    });
                    mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
                    root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
                    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.show();

                    mediaPlayer.play();
                    mediaView.setOnError(new EventHandler() {
                        public void handle(MediaErrorEvent t) {
                            // Handle asynchronous error in MediaView.
                            System.out.println("Handle asynchronous error in MediaView");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handle(Event arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // Handle synchronous error creating MediaPlayer.
                    System.out.println("Handle synchronous error creating MediaPlayer");
                }
            } catch (Exception mediaPlayerException) {
                mediaPlayerException.printStackTrace();
                // Handle exception in MediaPlayer constructor.
            }
        } else {
            // Handle synchronous error creating Media.
        }
    } catch (Exception mediaException) {
        mediaException.printStackTrace();
        // Handle exception in Media constructor.
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////
  /*  try{
        //File f=new File("C:/Wildlife.wmv");
        //URI u=new URI("C:\\Wildlife.wmv");

    Media media = new Media("file:///C:/share/test.mp4");
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView view = new MediaView(player);

    root.getChildren().add(view);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400, Color.BLACK);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    player.play();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
}}
```

**And this is the output getting after handling exception**

```
Handle asynchronous error in MediaPlayer object.
Handle asynchronous error in Media object
Handle asynchronous error in MediaPlayer object.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Answer to Original Question**

To solve your URISyntaxException you can pass a valid URL to your media constructor (for example "file:///C:/Wildlife.wmv").

But, even then, you won't be able to play your media file as [wmv is not a supported media container for JavaFX 2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html).

**Answers to Supplementary Questions from Comments**

> [Media](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29) arguments accepts a string which reperesents source file. 
>   So why the need of writing `file:///`?

Because the [Media constructor documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media%28java.lang.String%29) also specifies constraints on the input string:

> - The supplied URI must conform to RFC-2396 as required by [java.net.URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).
> - Only HTTP, FILE, and JAR URIs are supported.

In `file:///C:/Wildlife.wmv`, the URI scheme is file:, the // is the authority and could be followed by a windows share (if there was one), the next / is to show that it the path is absolute from the root rather than relative, then there is the windows drive specifier c:, then a / to indicate the root of c drive, then your actual filename Wildlife.wmv.  Without the full address, the input is malformed as the MediaPlayer would not know what protocol to use to read the media (that is what the file: scheme tells it), nor where to locate the media to be played.

Also note, that you can get a URI string from a File via:

```
new File(MEDIA_PATH).toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()
```

---

> I did as you said,now a pop up comes but video is not playing.

Well I did say, that even if you use the correct path to locate the media file, the media won't play because the media container format (wmv) is not supported.

The [media package javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) comprehensive example (entitled Error Handling) of catching potential errors which may occur when playing media so that you can catch all of the many errors that may occur in the many places the errors may occur and log them with a pull explanation and stack trace to work out precisely what went wrong.

---

> what changes do I have to make ?

You need to convert your media to a format which JavaFX 2.2 is able to process and for which appropriate codecs are available on your target machine.  If you want it to play anywhere JavaFX could be used, then you could convert it to a VP6 encoded FLV.  However, that isn't such a common format so you might have difficulty locating tools to do that conversion.  Instead, you could convert your WMV to a H.264 encoded video in an MP4 container and ensure that your platform has the right codecs installed (see the [JavaFX Media section of JavaFX Supported Configurations information on obtaining codecs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html)).  You can [google for a WMV to MP4 converter program](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=wmv%20to%20mp4) that you can use to convert your wmv file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and its useful so +1.But I have a query as per the http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html arguments accepts a string which reperesents source file.So why the need of writing **file:///**

Comment: I did as you said,now a pop up comes but video is not playing.May I know what changes do I have to make ?

Comment: forgot to say that I am using now mp4 format.As you said before WMV is not supported so tried with mp4 but forgot to mention

Comment: If you are now using MP4 encoding, and the video is not playing, then use the error handling logic I linked in my answer and, if you are unable to work out why you cannot play your video, add any resultant stack trace to your question.

Comment: I do not get any error,just pop comes and black background.You can see the screenshot that i have attached.

Comment: The code in your question does not contain the [error handling from the media package javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) which I linked in my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38845/discussion-between-jewelsea-and-javabeginner)

Comment: I have updated the code after printing stacktrace.Well if i am wrting source= **"file:///C:/share/test.mp4"** Then i get three lines that i have posted in my question( **and video is not playing**) however if i write source="http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv" then those three lines are not printed on the console.Also video is playing

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
File f = new File("C:\\Wildlife.wmv");

URI u = f.toURI();
```

if you need the url you can do `f.toURI().toURL()`

and then instanciate de media.

try an tell us sth.

Comment: can wmv files be played in javaFX

Comment: I think so, but i'm not expert at javaFx, you have an URISyntaxException..not an MediaUnsupportedException